# Chips/Fries Bake Identification

Tags: food-identification

Not sure if this belongs here but I've a family recipe that is effectively a pasta bake but instead of pasta you use skinny chips (UK) / french fries (USA).

It came from an Aunt who lived in Canada who came home to the UK. The recipe is as follows:

Chips/Fries,
Onion (fried),
Condensed chicken soup,
Peas,
Sweetcorn,
Cheese,
Cheese and Onion crisps (Chips in the US to add to the confusion),

Basically you mix it all together, add cheese as a topping then the crisps/chips on top and throw it in the oven for 45mins at 170 celcius.

It has been bugging me forever if this is an established recipe, it's great comfort food but I've not been able to find anything online about a "chip/fries oven bake".

Comment: Sounds like Dirty fries to me! They can come in loads of variations with different ingredients, I suspect it was just your aunts special concoction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a variation of a tater tot casserole, of which there are many variations.